# Erro de compilação

Tags: loop, while

Comecei AI há pouco tempo e não pesco muito disto... A ideia era usar o `while` para nos mostrar todos os números pares até 100 mas está sempre a dar erro e não consegui corrigir isto ainda.

```
while (i <= 100) {
   i += 1;
   if (i % 2 == 0)
       prinft('\n%d', i)
}
```

Comment: Não entendi o por que da marcação, a pergunta está dentro do escopo. Mesmo sendo um erro básico de sintaxe ele não deixou de ser ajudado pela comunidade. Acredito que seja essa a finalidade do StackOverflow. E mesmo a solução não sendo útil a usuários no futuro, pode ter sido útil para o autor da pergunta nesse momento.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold leia a descrição no amarelinho.

Comment: @bigown entendo, mas e se a solução apresentada ajudou a ele que fez a pergunta?

Comment: @FelipePaetzold ainda é um erro de digitação, não vai ajudar mais ninguém, não tem porque ela ficar aberta, nenhuma resposta nova dará uma uma solução melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Você digitou errado, não é prinft e sim printf.

Você pode usar o operador modulo também...

```
while (i <= 100) {
   i += 1;
   if (i % 2 == 0)
       printf('\n%d', i)
}
```

Comment: Pois já corrigi, mas já agora o que é que tenho que fazer para o valor final me dar 100 em vez de 102?

Comment: O seu código usa `while (i <= 100)`.. o `<=` é inclusivo, ou seja, ele vai executar o escopo do while quando o `i` for igual a 100. E dentro do escopo você está adicionando 2 ao valor de i, resultando em 102. Mude o `<=` pra `<`.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela ajuda ;).

Answer (score 0):

Você escreveu o nome da função printf erroneamente.

O correto é:

```
printf("Algum texto");
```

Tente prestar mais atenção nos erros que o compilador mostra pra você. 
Ele esta dizendo

> "Undefined reference to prinft".

Ou seja, ou você escreveu errado ou você não incluiu as bibliotecas corretas. 
No caso, você havia escrito errado

Comment: Obrigado, nem tinha reparado e estava a tentar corrigir o resto.